# build project for multiple runtime in dot net

Tags: c#, .net, build, csproj, dotnet-build

I tried to build a project for multiple targets.
I using net 5 framework, and I want to build app for win64 and linux64 runtimes.

**The problem**

> Missing linux 64 folder

The csproj file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    ...
  <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

then I ran cli command:

```
dotnet build "projectPath"
```

Result in folder:
[image]

Expected folder in results (when running with --runtime linux64)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After looking on MSDN
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)

dotnet publish section,
I understand that the dotnet build/publish process is framework depended to make the output executable targeted to the requested framework so with the configuration i mentioned above, the build resolves all availables targets and run them, but will not make the publish directory for each configured target